# Docker file builds fine in Debug but fails in release

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core

This is a Visual Studio, Worker project.

My docker file is below. It works fine in Debug mode. In release, it can’t find the dependent dlls. All dlls are in the \GWorker\bin\Release\net6.0

I’ve been avoiding this for years but now I need the release version.

Should there be a separate docker file for debug and release? The project was initially built in the first version of VS that supported docker.  I just tried reconstructing it from scratch. Same result.  Help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Dockerfile

```
#See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["GWorker/GWorker.csproj", "GWorker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "GWorker/GWorker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/GWorker"
RUN dotnet build "GWorker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "GWorker.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "GWorker.dll"]
```

---

Error messages are:

23:22:55:272    1>C:\Users\orgth\source\repos\CISOwareLLC\GWorker\GWorker\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #15 1.134   All projects are up-to-date for restore.
23:22:55:272    1>C:\Users\orgth\source\repos\CISOwareLLC\GWorker\GWorker\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #15 1.396 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ARTNet". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/GWorker/GWorker.csproj]
23:22:55:272    1>C:\Users\orgth\source\repos\CISOwareLLC\GWorker\GWorker\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #15 1.396 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "ClientMessagingx". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/GWorker/GWorker.csproj]
23:22:55:272    1>C:\Users\orgth\source\repos\CISOwareLLC\GWorker\GWorker\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #15 1.396 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "RemoteSitchDoc". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/GWorker/GWorker.csproj]
23:22:55:272    1>C:\Users\orgth\source\repos\CISOwareLLC\GWorker\GWorker\Dockerfile : error CTC1014: #15 1.396 /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.408/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2302,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "Remote_Standard". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [/src/GWorker/GWorker.csproj]
2